# NSPredicate issue with type objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an issue with `NSPRedicate`; it returns nil value. But my `ObjectType` sees it; maybe problem in `predecateFormat`?

I have 3 objects and I get it by **Type**. Source:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ObjectType) {
    FirstType,
    SecondType,
    ThdType,
};
```

Then I process with CoreData request:

```
- (NSArray *)objectsByType:(ObjectType)type{    
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[self objectEntity]];

        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.objectType == %d", type];
        [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [[self managedContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

    if(err){

        DLog(@"Failed to fetch objects %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }

    return objects;
}
```

I think problem is here.

Comment: Set your type to an NSNumber as that is what is stored in Core Data. `@"self.objectType == %@", @(type)`

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work...**Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate (objectType LIKE 1)**

Comment: Does that only happen if it is an `NSNumber` ?

Comment: in CoreData model objectType is NSNumber...

Comment: thank you sbarow, working. Problem was in another place too...

Comment: Cool happy to help, can I put that as an answer?

Comment: yeap, you can put this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your type to an `NSNumber` as that is what is stored in Core Data. `@"self.objectType == %@", @(type)`